# PHP language arrays and text

Tags: php

I have a text box and I wrote some text in it.
 the question is, how to put the written text inside an array, and then use the explode function to separate each word ?

Comment: Show us you text and the expected array.

Comment: You need to learn some PHP basics, no ? Try google first...

Comment: Take a look at the PHP manual and search around for topics regarding form submission.

Comment: Your text is in a string, you either [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) that string on a space character to get an array of words, or use [str_word_count()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) with a format code of 1 or 2

Comment: Put the "text box" in `<form>` tags then you can reference that text with $_GET['text box name']. You will see it in the URL also. Explode that.

Comment: I have created the text box already !
but how to explode it ? should I use the name or the id ?

Comment: <form name="input" action="separate.php" method="post">
Text: <input type="text" name="txt" id="txt">
<input type="submit" value="Separate">
</form>

Comment: @Alaa' Manna, your question's space can indeed receive code, it will be more beautiful and helpful as well.

Answer (score 2):

first get the value like this (I assume that you have a form and you send it by POST):

```
$name_of_array = $_POST['name_of_your_form_field'];
$separeted_vars = explode(' ', $name_of_array);
```

I hope this help you!

p.d: the $name_of_array isn't necessary that be array...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<?php

$words = explode(' ', $_POST['textbox_contents']);

?>
```

Comment: "this is some text to be separated" // this is written in a text box with a button called separate the array is gonna be used in the explode function the expected result is this is some text to be separated

Answer (score -1):

"this is some text to be separated" // this is written in a text box with a button called separate
the array is gonna be used in the explode function
the expected result is 
this
is
some
text
to 
be
separated

Comment: You should edit your question rather than putting an answer